# Find overlapping events in time (find overlapping intervals)

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, search, intervals

I have a list of events that are overlapping in time. An event is generally considered to span a period of time but events can have the same start and end times (i.e. point-in-time event). I'd like to mark events that belong together.

For example,

```
event | start_time | end_time
A     | 15:00:01   | 15:01:03
B     | 10:12:11   | 10:15:09
C     | 10:13:59   | 10:14:33
D     | 10:12:11   | 10:12:11
E     | 14:59:30   | 15:00:01
F     | 17:00:12   | 17:01:01
```

The list can go on longer but in the case above, events A and E should be grouped together and B, C, and D should be together and F is by itself. What is an efficient algorithm? I can do some simple interval scanning but I don't believe I know any algorithms specifically designed for this.

Comment: Why is this tagged `machine-learning`?

Comment: Search terms: "interval tree", "segment tree".